# Prometheus service discovery for Google Cloud Platform - not a valid hostname error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, prometheus

I've been trying to figure out why the hostname is invalid. I'm also discovering hosts in aws and using the same method. The exception is that the gce sd doesn't have an option for metrics path so I put the metrics path in the replacement field.

In order to access the metrics I've created at my endpoint, prometheus needs to use the public ip. My endpoint should be *public_ip:1234/my/metrics* which works fine for my aws discovery.

Config:

```
- job_name: 'gcp'
    gce_sd_configs:
      - project: my-project
        zone: us-west1-b
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels:
        - '__meta_gce_public_ip'
        regex: '(.*)'
        target_label: __address__
        replacement: '${1}:1234/my/metrics'
      - source_labels:
        - '__meta_gce_instance_id'
        target_label: 'instance'
      - source_labels:
        - '__meta_gce_instance_status'
        regex: 'TERMINATED'
        action: drop
```

Error message:

```
prometheus: level=error ts=2021-09-08T18:46:46.249Z caller=scrape.go:450 component="scrape manager" scrape_pool=gcp msg="creating targets failed" err="instance 2 in group GCE_project-prod_us-west1-b: \"12.345.67.89:1234/my/metrics\" is not a valid hostname"
```

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out you can use metrics_path for the gce discovery. Problem solved.